# How to clean completely ns2.35 in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ns2, ubuntu-15.04

I will clean ns2.35 from ubuntu15.04, I command follow run but this message created:

```
mada@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove ns2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ns2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

ns235 from ubuntu does not remove, while I work with it, I install ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz in Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt` will know packages.deb installed with `apt` (`apt-get`), not any manually installed files.

Removing a folder ns-allinone-2.35/ :

```
cd [path-to-folder-with-ns-allinone-2.35]
rm -rf ns-allinone-2.35/
```

If any ns2 executable´s in /usr/local/bin/: Must also be deleted manually.

Comment: Thanks alot Knud Larsen